# How can I require one of multiple properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Example:

```
public class Person
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Firstname")]
    public string firstname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Lastname")]
    public string lastname{ get; set; }

    // I want to require at least one of these 3 phones
    [DisplayName("Mobile Phone")]
    public string mobilephone { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Work Phone")]
    public string workphone { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Home Phone")]
    public string homephone { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have at least one phone number, but I don't care which one. Entering more than one phone number should also be possible.

Is there a clean way to do this? Or do I have to write the validation myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to write the validation yourself. Use `IValidatableObject`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I implemented a "Validate" Method that checked for "null" and empty string.